# JAR File won't work

Tags: java, deployment, jar

I have created a software that reads data from oracle database. when I am running it from JDeveloper everything works fine. But when I am deploying it, it starts the main class and when I press log in nothing happens. I have also included jdbc libraries and any external library I am using into the deployment profile. What is wrong here?

Comment: please paste the exception. with this description we cant help you!

Comment: There is no exception! I press login and nothing happens. As simple as that...

Comment: Have you tried running the jar from the command prompt instead of double-clicking..?

Comment: java -jar yourjar.jar

Comment: how do you run your program? do you have a correct META-INF file referencing the jars your jar needs to run?

Comment: at the meta-inf I added only the main class. That is what the profile asked for.

Comment: so you run your program like this? java -jar myjar.jar?

Comment: no I double click the jar file

Comment: i ran it like this and the terminal showed this: 

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jd
bc/pool/OracleDataSource
        at criminaldb.Login.getDBConnection(Login.java:124)
        at criminaldb.Login.loginbox_actionPerformed(Login.java:317)
        at criminaldb.Login.access$000(Login.java:30)
        at criminaldb.Login$1.actionPerformed(Login.java:99)`

I don't get these errors when I run it from JDev!

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

by clicking the jar and running it, your jar has to know where to look for the classpath. So please include in your jar's MANIFEST.MF file your classpath with all the required extra jars

It should be like this

```
Main-Class: com.mycompany.myMainClass
Class-Path: lib/jar1.jar lib/jar2.jar ...
```

with the thought that jars are included in sub directory lib

Comment: there are no other jars. I have a main class and other .java files all in the src folder of JDev

Comment: you have to reference your oracle jdbc driver somewhere. oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource

Comment: @Lambros please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you and solved your problem. thnx

Comment: so after putting the correct classpaths inside your manifest.mf file, what is the exception? are you sure the classpath points to the correct directory of the required jars? it doesnt make much sense...